# in-amp for strain gauge

Tags: measurement, voltage-measurement, strain-gage

I'm working on a project where I should send an overload signal if the strain is bigger than 40 ppm.

So far I found this answer:

[Strategy to balance a Wheatstone bridge for strain measurement](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/316724/strategy-to-balance-a-wheatstone-bridge-for-strain-measurement)

The wheatstone bridge consists 2x 120 ohm, GF 2 strain gauge and two 120 ohm 0.1% resistor.

Using the answer above I'd make it so that at 40 ppm the in-amp's output would drive a JFET.

I think that a ina-128 would be a good choice, but the power source is x piece 1,5 V battery so I'd need 4.

Is it a good choice, can you recommend a better for this application?

Answer (score 1):

Shopping questions area off-topic, but in general terms I would definitely go for one of the newer type of "zero drift" instrumentation amplifier that has a maximum supply voltage of ~5V or less.

Go to either a manufacturer (TI, AD, etc.) or to a distributor such as Digikey and do a parametric search, then compare datasheets.

A quick search yields, for example, the [AD8237](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD8237.pdf) which sports a 115uA current drain at 1.8 to 5.5V and 75uV maximum Vos.

Comment: Okay, so single supply solutions exist (I'm new to this), "zero drift" means those with 5 ppm gain drift? Nevermind I found titles with zero drift.

Comment: 'Zero drift' means they have an internal topology that uses switching techniques to reduce Vos and TCVos.

Comment: Just t make it clear, I just connect the two points of the wheatstone bridge to in+ and in-, Vout is output, I connect everything else as shown at Figure 72. Using Voltage Divider to Set Reference Voltage
Vs- is the negative, Vs+ is the positive end of the battery?

Comment: Other than that where or how can I ask questions like this? Before you mentioned I didn't even know about zero drift solutions, I only knew the offset voltage, that it'd batteries and that what is it used for. I found ina-128 at TI just I wasn't sure I know all important properties of an in-amp for this application.

Comment: I don't know what circuit you have in mind. Better to provide the whole schematic, preferably in another question. If it's just a comparator with no hysteresis you don't even need an in-amp, a zero-drift RRIO op-amp will do. 0.1% resistors are 100ppm so you will need to trim the circuit.

Comment: the circuit is like here at 2nd page:
https://www.egr.msu.edu/classes/ece480/capstone/spring15/group05/uploads/4/7/5/1/47515639/ece_480_app_note_justin_bauer.pdf

Comment: Still not sure what you are trying to do- measure or set a go/no-go limit

Comment: The task is to make a go/no-go limiter, as I have no better idea I would use a measuring circuit with offset, so it'd only "measure" at 40 ppm+.

Comment: If you have a circuit then it should be posted in the question, not buried in a link in a comment on an answer.